# How to Create vcf file of the contact which are in sim or in google account iPhone objective c

Tags: objective-c, backup, contacts, google-contacts-api, vcf-vcard

i want to get the backup of the contact files which resides in sim or google account or in iPhone, according to the users selection ... is it possible to do such thing...

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use the [Retrieving all contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts) from the Google Contacts API:

To retrieve all of a user's contacts, send an authorized GET request to the following URL:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full
```

With the appropriate value in place of userEmail.

However the other two you mentioned is not supported by the API.